# How to check if all values from one object are equal to values in another object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to compare some values from one object to values in another and check if they are equal

Example:

```
const mainObj = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 1};
const obj1 = {"d": 1, "e": 0};
const obj2 = {"a": 1, "b": 0};
const obj3 = {"a": 0, "d": 1};
const obj4 = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0 "d": 1};

mainObj === obj1 // false;
mainObj === obj2 // false;
mainObj === obj3 // true;
mainObj === obj4 // true;
```

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: please add your try. btw, you have all different object, even if the contain the same amount of keys and same values.

Comment: @NinaScholz my try was something in the lines of using `isMatch` and `isEqual` from lodash but those compare either if the objects are equal in all values or they compare if at least one value is in the object so it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following,

```js
const mainObj = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 1};
const obj1 = {"d": 1, "e": 0};
const obj2 = {"a": 1, "b": 0};
const obj3 = {"a": 0, "d": 1};
const obj4 = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 1};


const compareObj = (objA, objB) => {
  let res  = true;
  Object.keys(objB).forEach(key => {
    if(!objA.hasOwnProperty(key) || objA[key] !== objB[key]) {
      res = false;
    }
  })
  return res;
}

console.log(compareObj(mainObj, obj1));
console.log(compareObj(mainObj, obj2));
console.log(compareObj(mainObj, obj3));
console.log(compareObj(mainObj, obj4));
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed a "," in the 4th array,please change the code to

```
const mainObj = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 1};
const obj1 = {"d": 1, "e": 0};
const obj2 = {"a": 1, "b": 0};
const obj3 = {"a": 0, "d": 1};
const obj4 = {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0, "d": 1};

mainObj === obj1 // false;
mainObj === obj2 // false;
mainObj === obj3 // true;
mainObj === obj4 // true;
```

and try again